# Cómo utilizar % en Java y cómo sacar por pantalla valores que metes por teclado

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo a programar en Java y estoy realizando un ejercicio que me pide calcular si el primer número que se meta por teclado es múltiplo del segundo, y además que lo muestre por pantalla. No es algo excesivamente difícil, pero estoy bloqueado a la hora de mostrar el mensaje del resto y a la hora de sacar por pantalla los valores que entren por el teclado. Me explico.

```
System.out.println ("El resultado de la división de x/y es": +(x/y)";
 if (x%y>0)
 System.out.println ("El primer número no es múltiplo del segundo");
 then (x%y=0)
 System.out.println ("El primer número sí es múltiplo del segundo");
```

Vale, pues básicamente tengo dos dudas, de cara a hacer el código lo más limpio y eficiente posible:

a) ¿Existe alguna manera de mostrar con una única sentencia el resto y que te diga automáticamente si es múltiplo o no? Es decir, algo así (no sé si estaría correcto porque no sé si la información relacionada con el resto se pone así):

```
System.out.println ("El resto de la división de x%y es": + (x%y);
if (x%y>0)
System.out.println ("El primer número no es múltiplo del segundo");
then (x%y=0)
System.out.println ("El primer número sí es múltiplo del segundo");
```

b) ¿Cómo podríamos poner para que por pantalla en vez de que salga "el primer número si es múltiplo del segundo" salga algo así como "8 sí es múltiplo de 2", es decir, que coja los datos que hemos metido por teclado y los saque por pantalla con el System.out.println?

Muchas gracias, un saludo.

Comment: Sergio definitivamente necesitas revisar conceptos básicos, en java en este caso se usaría "else if" en lugar de "then", no debes usar ";" al final de estas sentencias, operadores. Debes también revisar como obtener un número multiplo.

Answer (score 1):

Se haría de la siguiente manera:

```
int resto;
int numero1;
int numero2;
    if (numero1%numero2==0)
        System.out.println(numero1 + " es múltiplo de " + numero2);  
    else  if (numero2%numero1==0)
        System.out.println(numero2 + " es múltiplo de " + numero1);
     else
        System.out.println("No son multiplos");
```

Siempre puedes optimizarlo para que sea más eficiente y realizar menos operaciones, pero de esta manera también lograrías el resultado. Espero que te haya ayudado.

Answer (score 1):

> ¿Existe alguna manera de mostrar con una única sentencia el resto y
>   que te diga automáticamente si es múltiplo o no?

Te sugiero primeramente revisar [múltiplos de un número](https://www.sangakoo.com/es/temas/divisores-y-multiplos-de-un-numero), ahora para imprimir los textos con los valores calculados, puedes usar [String.format()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html) que requiere una cadena de formato y una lista de argumentos, donde puedes especificar el tipo de dato que aparecerá en la cadena, en este caso [entero decimal](https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples) usando %d :

```
  int x = 21;
  int y = 3;
  int resultado = x%y;

  System.out.println (String.format("El resto de la división de %d entre %d es: %d", x,y, x%y));

  if (resultado == 0)
      System.out.println (String.format("El primer número %d es múltiplo del segundo %d", x , y));                      
  else if (resultado > 0)
      System.out.println (String.format("El primer número %d NO es múltiplo del segundo %d", x , y));
```

> ¿Cómo podríamos poner para que por pantalla en vez de que salga "el
>   primer número si es múltiplo del segundo" salga algo así como "8 sí es
>   múltiplo de 2", es decir, que coja los datos que hemos metido por
>   teclado y los saque por pantalla con el System.out.println?

Puedes usar la clase [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) para crear un lector y asignar los valores introducidos a variables:

```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //Crea el lector
      System.out.println("Ingrese valor de x:");
      int x = sc.nextInt();  //asigna valor introducido por teclado a variable
      System.out.println("Ingrese valor de y:");
      int y = sc.nextInt();  //asigna valor introducido por teclado a variable
```

De esta forma puedes introducir los datos y determinar si el número es multiplo:

```
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Ingrese valor de x:");
  int x = sc.nextInt(); 
  System.out.println("Ingrese valor de y:");
  int y = sc.nextInt(); 

  int resultado = x%y;

  System.out.println (String.format("El resto de la división de %d entre %d es: %d", x,y, x%y));

  if (resultado == 0)
      System.out.println (String.format("El primer número %d es múltiplo del segundo %d", x , y));                      
  else if (resultado > 0)
      System.out.println (String.format("El primer número %d NO es múltiplo del segundo %d", x , y));
```