# Fallo en código sobre si x es múltiplo de y, en Java

Tags: java

Estoy aprendiendo a programar y estoy haciendo un ejercicio que te solicita que metas dos números por teclado y el programa te saque si el primero es múltiplo del segundo o no. La cosa es que el código me da distintos errores y no acabo de pillar en qué me estoy equivocando. Aquí el código:

```
 1. public class Ejercicio {
 2.   public static void main(String[] args) {
 3.   Scanner Ejercicio= new Scanner (System.in);
 4.   int x, y;
 5.   System.out.println ("Introduzca el primer número");
 6.   x = Ejercicio.nextInt();
 7.   System.out.println ("Introduzca el segundo número");
 8.   y= Ejercicio.nextInt();
 9.   System.out.printIn ("Dividimos x entre y y el resultado es": +(x/y));
 10.   if (x%y=0)) {
 11.       System.print.out ("El primer número es múltiplo del segundo");
 12.       } 
 13.   else {
 14.       System.print.out ("El primer número no es múltiplo del segundo");
 15.           }
```

Aquí los fallos que me da:

- Línea 9: me dice

  > `)` expected. Not a statement. `;` expected. Cannot find symbol. Symbol: method println (String). Location: variable out of type PrintStream.

No tengo ni idea a qué se refiere.

- Línea 10:

  > Illegal start of expression. Unexpected type. Required variable. Found: value.

No comprendo por qué me dice esto si un `ìf` que yo sepa se inicia así y además la variable si está puesta, ya que están puestas `x` e `y`.

- Línea 11:

  > cannot find symbol. Symbol: variable print. Location: class System.

No sé a qué se refiere.

- Línea 13:

  > else without if.

No comprendo por qué me dice esto si el `if` está más arriba.

- Línea 14:

  > cannot find symbol. Symbol: variable print. Location: class System.

No sé a qué se refiere.

¿Alguien me ayuda? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Sergio en una [anterior pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/143613/c%C3%B3mo-utilizar-en-java-y-c%C3%B3mo-sacar-por-pantalla-valores-que-metes-por-teclado) que me parece duplicado de esta, te sugerí : "Sergio definitivamente necesitas revisar conceptos básicos en java en este caso se usaría "else if" en lugar de "then", no debes usar ";" al final de estas sentencias, operadores. Debes también revisar como obtener un número multiplo."  En este caso tienes varios errores que indican que debes revisar conceptos básicos.

Comment: En la L9 tienes un error de sintaxis: `printIn` en vez de **`println`**. El error de la L10 podría ser consecuencia de este. En L11 y L14 tienes otro error de sintaxis, ya que `System.print.out`  no existe, se escribe al revés: **`System.out.print`**. Revisa también la convención de nombres. Por ejemplo llamas al escáner con el mismo nombre que la clase. Y para evitar sorpresas, haz los cálculos en variables y compara éstas, no los cálculos directamente...

Answer (score 1):

Solo para completar lo que ya te esta recomendando Jorge (al parecer desde hace varias preguntas), te voy a explicar tus errores, y si, vas a tener que leer conceptos basicos de programacion y sobre todo de java.

> -Línea 9: me dice ) expected. Not a statement. ; expected. Cannot find symbol. Symbol: method println (String). Location: variable out of
>   type PrintStream. No tengo ni idea a qué se refiere.

```
 9.   System.out.println ("Dividimos x entre y y el resultado es": +(x/y));
```

y si.. mira donde esta cerrado tu ", comparado con donde se deberia cerrar. es un claro error tipografico. : no es nada para el lenguaje, por lo tanto si esta afuera de las comillas, esta mal.
Ademas tu codigo dice printIn, cuando deberia ser println.
Deberia ser:

```
 9.   System.out.println ("Dividimos x entre y y el resultado es: " +(x/y));
```

> -Línea 10: Illegal start of expression. Unexpected type. Required variable. Found: value. No comprendo por qué me dice esto si un ìf que
>   yo sepa se inicia así y además la variable si está puesta, ya que
>   están puestas x e y.

```
10.   if (x%y=0)) {
```

el simbolo = se usa para igualar una variable a un valor (ya sea constante u otra variable). Para saber si dos valores son iguales, se usa ==. ademas, hay un problema de que operador se ejecuta antes que otro (revisa conceptos sobre eso). Deberia ser:

```
10.   if ( (x%y) == 0)) {
```

> -Línea 11: cannot find symbol. Symbol: variable print. Location: class System. No sé a qué se refiere. (y 14 tambien)

```
11.       System.print.out ("El primer número es múltiplo del segundo");
```

Si antes hiciste `System.out.println`, porque ahora haces algo al reves, y no entendes que la clase System no tiene un objeto print? (pero si tiene un objeto out, que a su vez tiene un metodo print).

> -Línea 13: else without if. No comprendo por qué me dice esto si el if está más arriba.

Este error, no es un problema en si, se da porque te da error la linea del if. cuando arregles eso, este se arregla solo.

Por favor, lee sobre los conceptos del lenguaje...

Comment: Que noooo, que `System.out.printIn`  no aplica para este caso.

Comment: que ya lo cambie hombre! tenia dos fallos esa linea se me paso el otro ;) @A.Cedano

Answer (score 0):

Tienes bastantes fallos, deberías revisar bastantes conceptos básicos y sobretodo utilizar algún editor que te vaya indicando que lineas están mal y por qué antes de compilar el programa.

Aun así, como no se nace aprendiendo, intentaré decirte donde tienes los fallos:

```
Linea 9: es println y no printIn (es l y no I). Además los dos puntos deben ir dentro de las comillas.
Linea 10: 'x%y=0' es una asignación (y mal hecha), para hacer una comprobación debería ser 'x%y==0'. Además estas cerrando el paréntesis mal (te sobra un ')').
Lineas 11 y 14: es `System.out.print` y no `System.print.out`
```

El código corregido quedaría asi:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
     Scanner Ejercicio= new Scanner (System.in);
     int x, y;
     System.out.println ("Introduzca el primer número");
     x = Ejercicio.nextInt();
     System.out.println ("Introduzca el segundo número");
     y= Ejercicio.nextInt();
     System.out.println ("Dividimos x entre y y el resultado es: " +(x/y));
     if (x%y==0) {
         System.out.print ("El primer número es múltiplo del segundo");
     } 
     else {
         System.out.print ("El primer número no es múltiplo del segundo");
     }
}
```

Comment: ¿Por qué he recibido un voto negativo? Me gustaría que por lo menos comentasen donde está el error, para editar o saber cómo contestar correctamente estas preguntas. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Tiene error de sintaxis en el `if` y en la linea 9

```
  System.out.println("Dividimos x entre y y el resultado es: "+(x/y));
```

es colocar la condicional de la siguiente manera

```
if (x%y==0) {
      System.out.println("El primer número es múltiplo del segundo");
    } 
else {
      System.out.println("El primer número no es múltiplo del segundo")           }
```

Reforzar los conceptos básicos de sintaxis de java.

Comment: @A.Cedano Cálmese, por copear y pegar se me fue out.printIn, si esa va ser la manera de comentar favor guárdese sus comentarios, comentarios de ese tipo sobran y no lo van a hacer parecer que sabe mas que todos.

Comment: Recibo bien la criticas constructivas, pero el comentario parece mas un regaño u otra cosa, menos una critica constructiva. Ya corregí mi respuesta para dar fin a este tema

Comment: Comentarios borrados y perdona si te sentiste ofendido, no era mi intención. Los comentarios miran a eso, a provocar un mejoramiento de la respuesta, del cual todos nos beneficiamos. Saludos.